# NODE_APP_INSTANCE similar variable inside kubernetes node app

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, environment-variables, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-statefulset

When we use `PM2` in cluster mode, we can find out the instance number inside node app using `process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE`, but how we can find that inside a kubernetes cluster without `pm2`. I'm looking for similar like find replica instance number or etc.

Imagine a node app with 2 or more replicas and we need to run `node-cron` scheduler only inside one of pods.

Comment: did you find any answer?

Comment: @moeinrahimi Yes, I've added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that when use `Statefulset` instead of the `Deployment` then it's possible to inject the determinable POD name as an environment variable.

```
  ...
  containers:
     ...
     env:
     - name: "POD_NAME"
       valueFrom:
         fieldRef:
           fieldPath: metadata.name
```

And then `POD_NAME` variable has the value like this: pod-0 or pod-1 and so on.
So we can find out the instance number with that ordinal number.